# Firestore Rules break if the document path has a comma

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So, I am building a multi tenant application which involves multitude of collections and user invitation. Since I don't know which user ID the signup is going to use and I want the companies to start making changes and updates to their user data I am pre setting the user ID and I use it in several paths as:

```
/companies/{company}/customers/{userId}
/users/{userId}
```

Now, this userId is pretty much the email with the dot replaced by a comma. The dot is a character not allowed in firebase but the comma is, and viceversa with emails so it makes sense and there is no problem there.

The issue is when I need to make some rules. For example I have this in the configuration since I want admins to access every company:

```
  function cleanEmail(){
        return request.auth.token.email.split('.').join(',') //Here I also tried %2C
    }

    function isSuperadmin() {
      return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/admins/$(cleanEmail()))
    }


 match /companies/{company} {
      allow write: if isSuperadmin();
      allow read: if isSuperadmin() || belongsToCompany(company)
}
```

The simulator was breaking but I could not understand why, so I even sent a bug report. Eventually I tried making the path hard coded and then I found the problem:

```
function isSuperadmin() {
      return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/admins/test,account@gmail,com) //Same issue with get()
    }
```

[image]

I tried with exists() because I thought it could be a bug with get() but the issue remains. I believe this should be a bug since that is a valid Firestore path and I have seen some people already using this "clean email" strategy.

Funny thing is that this was not happening during first testing and I realized that this bug only happens if the comma is BEFORE the @. If you remove the one before that, and leave the second one, seems to work:

[image]

I might add a new step to the clean email that turns that into base64 and that might work tho. If someone has a solution great.

Comment: Most systems use the UID as the doc name, (which is letters and numbers).  The rules can refer to it as `request.auth.uid`.  Seems a better choice, too, because the UID is attached to an account whose email address and other contact info can vary over time.

Comment: I understand but I can't do that as I explain because I want to invite users and I don't know which UID they are going to have, so I can't create the rules in a somehow deterministic approach. I could create users when the company invites them and I can have the UID then BUT that means the user is already created so the end user needs to reset their password to get in. Not very user friendly. Since the user will be invited (as in, the auth user does not exists yet) I need a way to store data in a way that I know exactly where this user is going to be

Comment: This won't be a problem if I could choose which UID the user gets when they register, because I can see if he has been invited and already has a profile in the database. So I just assign the same ID the database created and that is it.

Comment: Not sure this would work for you, but my system invites users, then on the `functions.auth.user().onCreate` hook in the cloud creates a document for them in a collection named with their UID.  The app can see the UID, and so can the rules.  I can show you in an answer if you think this is in the ballpark.

Comment: Well, I am doing mostly that, as I have a hook for the onCreate too. How do you handle data that you'd want to modify on behalf of the user once they finally register? In my user case, this is a travel agency, that invites the user and before they accept the invite, they can generate their trip and everything. Issue with this is that, for example, this trip record won't have the information for the UID as the UID does not exists yet :) Are you blocking all user data information until they accept the invite? I am thinking if I can workaround this by using just different queries based on email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similar that looks like this in outline:

```
/invitation
    /fb-generated-doc-name
        email: somecustomer@gmail.com
        trip: db-ref-to-trip

/usertrips
    /doc-name-is-UID
        trip: db-ref-to-trip

/trips
   /fb-generated-doc-name
       { ... describes the trip ... }
```

The outline for onCreate auth'd user is:

```
exports.authDidCreateUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((authUser, context) => {
  /* 
      find invitation where email == authUser.email
      let docref = collection('usertrips').doc(authUser.uid)
      docref.set({ trip: invitation.trip })
  */
});
```

Comment: This might help me. Give me a few days to try something out. Thanks!

Comment: I am going to award you the answer, just give me a few days as I want to see if someone from Firebase joins and confirms a bug. I am actually going to resolve it in a different way. I'll create an anonymous user if it does not exists, and then copy data over once the user finally registers. This way I can make sure the rules are easier to handle. In my head it should work

Comment: So eventually I ended up doing something similar + temporary anonymous users which "upgrade" to regular users if the user registers. Thanks!